# How to cut finger/toe nails perfectly round on the first attempt

Tags: personal-care

Hi I am struggling to find the fastest easiest way to cut nails smoothly without having to snip a single nail several times especially the toe nails. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: With a single snip? I'll be interested it anyone has a solution for that. Personally, I do 5-6 quick snips of each nail as I'm gradually moving the nail clippers around it. My nails come out pretty uniform. (My wife likes the way they look, so I've got a second opinion to back me up!)

Comment: I had a friend who allowed his mom to cut his finger nails. She did it so smoothly, however it took her over 10 minutes (I still remember waiting when we were going out with friends). I was thinking perhaps there is a electronic version of nail clippers which cut each nail once. It's the  21st century! Perhaps someone could modify an old CIA nail torture kit and ship it to me. @BrettFromLA

Comment: You'd have to be sure you modified it 100% correctly!! But in the meantime, Google "electric nail trimmer" and you'll find a few options.

Answer (score 1):

Toenail clippers are intentionally made with a convex edge to help prevent ingrown toenails: ["When trimming your toenail, cut the edge straight across. Do not round the corners."](http://www.curvecorrect.com/how-to-prevent-ingrown-toenails/) ["Guide the clippers straight across the nail of each toe and avoid cutting nails into a curved shape."](http://www.everydayhealth.com/foot-health/toenail-cutting-tips.aspx)

If the appearance bothers you, gently file the edges after clipping.